# C# Removing last two characters from textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, autoformatting

I have a textbox which I'm trying to implement automatic formatting on for a phone number.

I would like to remove the last two characters of the textbox if the user presses the delete key and the last character of the string in the textbox is `'-'`.

I am attempting to do this through substring removal, but with no luck.  Thanks

```
private void phoneNumberTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)
            {
                if (phoneNumberTextBox.Text.Length != 0)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToChar(phoneNumberTextBox.Text.Substring(phoneNumberTextBox.Text.Length - 1)) == '-')
                    {
                        phoneNumberTextBox.Text.Substring(0, phoneNumberTextBox.Text.Length - 2);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: http://www.visual-basic-tutorials.com/Tutorials/Controls/MaskedTextBox.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Substring()` returns a new string instance and leaves the current instance unchanged. Because of this, your call just creates a new temporary string but because you don't do anything with it, it gets thrown away immediately.

To make the change stick, you need to assign the result of `Substring()` back to the textbox, like so:

```
phoneNumberTextBox.Text = phoneNumberTextBox.Text.Substring(0,
    phoneNumberTextBox.Text.Length - 2);
```

Make sure you check the length of the string first to avoid problems with handling short string (less than 2 characters).

Also, if you want to limit the number of characters in the textbox, just use the [`MaxLength`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.maxlength(v=vs.110).aspx) property instead. You don't have to deal with handling length and typing that way.

Comment: This worked like a charm!  Thanks.  Now I'm having an issue where the text cursor moves to the beginning of the textbox when the operation completes.

Comment: @AlexEdwards That happens because you shorten the string - the caret would then be at an invalid position so it moves to the beginning of the string. Why don't you just set the `MaxLength` property of the textbox?

Comment: @AlexEdwards I added a link to `MaxLength` - that may work better for you.

Comment: I already have MaxLength set for the general format of the number xxx-xxx-xxxx.  Is there any way I could have the caret move to the end of the string?

Comment: @AlexEdwards You can use the `SelectionStart` property for that - just move it to the end of the text.

Comment: If it adds to the context better I'm automatically appending '-' when the user types the phone number for added user friendliness and readability.

Comment: @AlexEdwards Have you looked into using `MaskedTextBox` instead? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @xxbbxx a user just linked me the documentation to that, I may give that a look later.  I'm already near complete with this though so I might pull through with this for now and use 'MaskedTextBox' down the road.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

For the 2 char removal could do:

```
phoneNumberTextBox.Text = phoneNumberTextBox.Text.Remove(phoneNumberTextBox.Text.Length - 2, 2);
```

For the key pressing part might be that you have to enable the KeyPreview on you form.

Wow sry for the editing doing mistakes all over.